# How to use nested SELECTs in Mysql with LIKE?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-like

Assume this is the query I need:

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `keywords` LIKE "%(SELECT `key` FROM `keywords` WHERE `slug` = '%d8%af%db%8c%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b1' LIMIT 1)%"
```

Currently it doesn't work and returns zero results while there are records that satisfy the condition.
I wonder what is the problem here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE keywords LIKE
    CONCAT('%', (SELECT `key` FROM `keywords` 
        WHERE `slug` = '%d8%af%db%8c%d9%88%d8%a7%d8%b1' LIMIT 1), '%');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, not sure if it will work...

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE keywords LIKE "%" + (SELECT key FROM keywords WHERE slug = 'something' LIMIT 1) + "%";
```

Comment: Stupidly, '+' doesn't concatenate strings in MySQL - only in just about EVERY other SQL database out there.

Answer (score 1):

Another work example with like and nested SELECT:

```
SELECT COUNT(email) as count FROM table1 t1 
JOIN (
      SELECT company_domains as emailext FROM table2 WHERE company = 'DELL'
     ) t2 
ON t1.email LIKE CONCAT('%', emailext) WHERE t1.event='PC Global Conference";
```

Task was to count participants at an event(s) with filter if email extension equal to multiple company domains. Will be great if someone find this useful